# required country combobox

Tags: java, locale, country

In my project I hava one field that is country name.Till now I am inserting the country name on textfield. I want the combobox which already contain all the country name. Is there any combobox like that in java?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using swing then you have [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html). or in Webproject in html you have [Select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Swing, there's the `JComboBox` class. You can use it like this:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.addItem("First item");
comboBox.addItem("Second item");
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
{            
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            System.out.println("Item " + e.getItem() + " selected");
        else
            System.out.println("Item " + e.getItem() + " deselected");
    }
});
System.out.println("Selected item: " + comboBox.getSelectedItem());
```

Comment: Notice you can even get the Locale list of the JVM (to populate your JComboBox) by calling `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a pre-populated JComboBox with all the countries, but you can easily find a list of countries on the web, declare them as a constant array, and use that array to populate a JComboBox or whatever you choose to use. Although a constant array is probably bad practice, because the list will probably change slowly over time.

A better approach would be to get them from Java using code like this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/Getalistofcountrynames.htm

However that does rely on the JDK you are using in production being up-to-date with the current list of countries. And while you are waiting for a JDK to be released with a new country list when it changes, your app will use the incorrect old list (for a few days at least). So you might want to read them from a file or database instead.